Unable to import "io.restassured" package in eclipse
I am writing code for APi Automation Testing using Selenium with Java & Restassured.
If I try to import Restassurred packages using elow line of code -
import io.restassured.RestAssured;
import io.restassured.path.json.JsonPath;
it's giving import can't be resolved error
tried the code -
import io.restassured.RestAssured;
import io.restassured.path.json.JsonPath;
Expected results -
restassured packages should be successfully imported
Actual -
it's giving import can't be resolved error

